# Does the libreoffice calc auto change command language?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I have a document made in a English version of Libre Office calc and I need to open it in a Polish version of this program the commands are translated so "IF" becomes "JEŻELI". What happens when I open this document in Polish version of the program will it auto-change the commands to match the Polish ones or it will say "?NAME" or something? I need answer really fast because i need this document to work for tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will show the Calc functions in Polish, and there will not be any errors.

I unzipped an .ods file created with a Spanish user interface, and it still showed the English function name in the XML code.  So apparently English is always used as underlying, and function names gets translated to the user interface language.